# Unable to read a PDF file using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to fill in a PDF form using JAVA, but when I tried to get the fields using the below code the list is empty.

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(filename);
PDAcroForm pdform = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
List<PDField> field = pdform.getFields();
```

Then I tried to read the file using PDFStripper

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
System.out.println(stripper.getText(pdDoc));
```

and the ouput was as follows

"Please wait...

If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF 
viewer may not be able to display this type of document.

You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by 
visiting  http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.

For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit  http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader.

Windows is either a registered trademark or a trademark of Microsoft Corporation in the United States and/or other countries. Mac is a trademark 
of Apple Inc., registered in the United States and other countries. Linux is the registered trademark of Linus Torvalds in the U.S. and other 
countries."

But I'm able to open the file manually and fill the fields as well. I've tried other tools like iText also. But again I wasn't able to get the fields.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late to answer but anyway why not. You can get empty list if your pdf file has XFA structure.

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(filename);
PDAcroForm pdform = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
List<PDField> field = pdform.getFields();
```

Use these code lines to start working with pdf:

```
PDXFA xfa = pdform.getXFA();
Document xfaDocument = xfa.getDocument();
NodeList elements = xfaDocument.getElementsByTagName( "SomeElement" );
```

Comment: How can you check whether that's the case or not?

Comment: Use the following 'if' statement: `if ( pdform.getFields().isEmpty ) { //XFA case } else { //AcroForm case }`

Answer (score 0):

While struggling with Alfresco's content search abilities, I've had some trouble with pdfbox (used by Alfresco to extract text and metadata) reading PDF files written by old applications (like QuarkXPress) that use old Acrobat 4.0 format. This old format pdfbox seems to be unable to extract metadata or text from it, although the files were perfectly viewable with any PDF reader application.

The solution was having all old PFD files re-printed (saved as...) using a more modern PDF format (like 10.0 for instance). This can be done in a row using some bash scripting.

I directly didn't try intermediate Acrobat versions among 4.0 and 10.0.